# Information retrieval Measures of association/correlation

Tags: math, information-retrieval, pearson-correlation

I try to understand correlation measures of terms.

Therefore I found the following exercise:
Which term is more correlated/associated with the term `pool`: `duck` or `fish`? Use the pearson-correlation, the dice-correlation, the mutual information and the expected mutual information.

I have the following information given (count of that term in each document):

```
Term | D1 | D2  
pool | 0 | 23  
duck | 23 | 10  
fish | 4 | 8
```

To get the score for the told algorithms I need basically 4 measures:

```
Frequency Term A  
Frequency Term B  
Number of docments  
Frequency Term A and Term B
```

Could you get me a quick example how to get the similarity of the term pool and duck? I already searched the web and stackoverflow, but didn't find an example of document-level with just this few informations given.

I already tried the following measures, but this wouldn't respect the absolute occurence of each term, which doesn't seem correct:

```
Frequency Term pool: 1 (occurse in 1 document)  
Frequency Term duck: 2 (occurse in 2 document)  
Number of docments: 2  
Frequency Term pool and Term duck: 1 (occure together only in 1 document)
```

I also tried the following measures, but then I don't know how the combined frequency should be calculated:

```
Frequency Term pool: 23  
Frequency Term duck: 33  
Number of docments: 2  
Frequency Term pool and Term duck: ?
```

I would have expected some more information in the exercise. Maybe someone of you could help me how to get results with this few informations?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: This is an interesting question, but it's more suitable from stats.stackexchange.com.